# How to reset controlTimeout in react-native-video ref

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I have a Video component that uses `react-native-video-controls` and everything works great except for one thing:

The custom buttons I use to skip/seek and play/pause don't reset the controlTimeout value (the delay between last interaction and the hideControls action that shows/hides the controls over the video. In this sense, no matter how many times you press my buttons, the timeout just counts down and disappears, rather than resetting on each press.

I should be able to continuously press buttons to keep the controls on indefinitely (as long as the timer doesn't hit the limit). How would I reset the controlTimeout value?

My Video component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { VideoProperties } from 'react-native-video';
import Video from 'react-native-video-controls';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Image } from 'react-native-elements';
import { colors } from '../styles/colorPalette';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useTheme } from '../contexts/ThemeContext';
import { ReactNativeProps } from 'react-native-render-html';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

interface VideoPlayerProps extends VideoProperties {
  autoPlay?: boolean
  categoryOverlay?: boolean | string
  disableSeekSkip?: boolean
  ref?: any
}

const VideoPlayer = (props: VideoPlayerProps & ReactNativeProps) => {
  const [vidAspectRatio, setVidAspectRatio] = useState(1.75)
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [lastTouched, setLastTouched] = useState(0)
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(!props.paused || false);
  const [controlsActive, setControlsActive] = useState(false);
  const { darkMode } = useTheme();
  const { categoryOverlay, disableSeekSkip = false, source } = props;
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const videoRef = useRef<Video>(null);

  const handleError = (e: any) => {
    console.log("ERROR: ", e)
  }

  const handleSeek = (num: number) => {
    if (!videoRef.current || videoRef.current.state.seeking === true || (Date.now() - lastTouched < 250)) {
      return
    } else {
    videoRef.current.player.ref.seek(Math.max(0, Math.min((videoRef.current.state.currentTime + num), videoRef.current.state.duration)))
    setLastTouched(Date.now())
    }
  }

  const handleHeight = (res: any) => {
    // set height and duration
    duration && setDuration(res.duration ?? null);
    setVidAspectRatio(res.naturalSize ? (res.naturalSize.width / res.naturalSize.height) : 1.75);
  }

  const handlePause = (res: any) => {
    // The logic to handle the pause/play logic
    res.playbackRate === 0 ? setIsPlaying(false) : setIsPlaying(true);
  }

  const handlePlayPausePress = () => {
    isPlaying ? setIsPlaying(false) : setIsPlaying(true)
  }

  const handleProgress = (progress: any) => {
    setProgress(progress.atValue);
  }

  const handleSetControlsActive = (active: boolean) => {
    setControlsActive(active)
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      position: 'relative',
      resizeMode: 'cover',
      aspectRatio: vidAspectRatio ? vidAspectRatio : 1.75,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    controls: {
    },
    controlsImage: {
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      width: '100%',
    },
    playIcon: {
      color: darkMode ? colors.primary.purple4 : "#fff",
      fontSize: 30,
      marginHorizontal: 30,
    },
    playIconContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignItems: 'center',
      paddingHorizontal: 15,
      paddingVertical: 7.5,
      borderRadius: 10,
    },
    video: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    },
    videoPlayer: {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
    },
    videoPoster: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      resizeMode: 'cover',
    },
    videoWrapper: {
      position: 'absolute',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    },
    volumeOverlay: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
    },
    categoryOverlay: {
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      paddingVertical: 5,
      position: 'absolute',
      color: '#fff',
      bottom: 10,
      right: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .75)',
      borderRadius: 10,
      zIndex: 999,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
    },
  });

  const convertTime = (seconds: number) => {
    const secsRemaining = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    return `${Math.floor(seconds / 60)}:${secsRemaining < 10 ? '0' + secsRemaining : secsRemaining}`
  }

  const convertTimeV2 = (secs: number) => {
    var hours   = Math.floor(secs / 3600)
    var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60
    var seconds = Math.floor(secs % 60)

    return [hours,minutes,seconds]
        .map(v => v < 10 ? "0" + v : v)
        .filter((v,i) => v !== "00" || i > 0)
        .join(":")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) console.log("ERROR", error)
  }, [error])
  
  return (
    <Animated.View  style={styles.container}>
      { (controlsActive || !isPlaying) && 
        <View style={styles.volumeOverlay}>
          <Image containerStyle={{height: 60, width: 60}} source={videoRef.current.state.muted ? require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/volume-muted.png') : require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/volume-on.png') }/>
        </View>
      }
      <View style={styles.videoWrapper}>
        <Video
          ref={videoRef}
          // controls={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false} /* Added Platform flag to circumvent iOS control bug for now */
          {...props}
          source={source}
          showOnStart
          disableBack
          disableFullscreen
          disablePlayPause
          disableSeekbar={disableSeekSkip}
          disableTimer={disableSeekSkip}
          paused={(!isPlaying || !isFocused) || props.paused}
          onLoad={handleHeight}
          onError={handleError}
          onHideControls={() => handleSetControlsActive(false)}
          onShowControls={() => handleSetControlsActive(true)}
          onPlaybackRateChange={handlePause}
          onProgress={handleProgress}
          seekColor="#a146b7" 
          controlTimeout={3000}
          style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}}
          containerStyle={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}}
        />
      </View>
      {categoryOverlay && progress === 1 && 
        <View style={styles.categoryOverlay}>
          <Text style={{color: "#fff", textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>{(typeof categoryOverlay === 'boolean') && duration ? convertTime(duration) : categoryOverlay}</Text>
        </View>
      }
      { (progress === 1 && !isPlaying) && <View style={styles.videoPoster}><Image style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={{ uri: `https://home.test.com${props.poster}` }} /></View> }
      { (controlsActive || !isPlaying) && 
        <View style={styles.playIconContainer}>
          { !disableSeekSkip && <TouchableOpacity disabled={videoRef.current.state.currentTime == 0 || videoRef.current.state.seeking} onPress={() => handleSeek(-15)}>
            <Image containerStyle={{height: 60, width: 60}} style={styles.controlsImage} source={require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/back-15s.png')}/>
          </TouchableOpacity> }
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePlayPausePress}>
            <Image containerStyle={{height: 60, width: 60}} source={isPlaying ? require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/pause-video-white.png') : require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/play-video-white.png')}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          { !disableSeekSkip && <TouchableOpacity disabled={videoRef.current.state.currentTime == videoRef.current.state.duration || videoRef.current.state.seeking} onPress={() => handleSeek(15)}>
            <Image containerStyle={{height: 60, width: 60}} style={styles.controlsImage} source={require('../assets/icons/Miscellaneous/Video_Controls/skip-15s.png')}/>
          </TouchableOpacity> }
        </View> }
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

export default React.memo(VideoPlayer)
```

Comment: Could you provide some code so that anyone can understand your question better.

Comment: I think it's more of a general 'do you know' question - but I've added code if it helps. There's a prop in videoRef (the ref) called player.controlTimeout that increments a timer, and clears the controls if it exceeds the threshold. When my custom buttons are pressed, they don't reset the timer, so the controls still close even after tapping.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky solution but you can remove/edit/implement code in
react-native-video-controls/[VideoPlayer.js](https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls/blob/4d7f398c9bb6ed3b2044c52805dc2f0220351298/VideoPlayer.js)
Find the related part in the code(starts at line 336) and focus on `setControlTimeout`, `clearControlTimeout`, `resetControlTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. Maybe you can use them in your custom buttons directly.

Comment: That's the thing. I see a clearTimeout function, as well as a resetTImeout function inside VideoiPlayer.js. I just don't know how to call it from within a ref. It's not exposed. I just find it weird that you can't hook into it when you add custom buttons. :/